# Use awk column variable inside a function with a parameter

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

My problem is the following.I have declared a function in my script

```
 crc_detection(){

  EVTLOG_PATH=$(/share/st/scripts/stlatest -d -n $1)

  echo "<td>" >> FPATH/mail.out

  grep "rcfc" $FPATH/*$1/showport.out|awk '{print $1}'|while read line
  do
     if find ${EVTLOG_PATH}/evtlog -name "*.debug" |tail -n 6|xargs grep "Invalid CRC"|grep -q "sw_port:${line}";
     then
       echo Port: $line >> $FPATH/mail.out
     fi


  done
```

And I pass and argument to the function.What's troubling is that functions use $1 , $2 ... as the arguments, which leaves awk without the usual variable for the columnt ID.So right now instead of passing $1 (first column) it reads the argument passed to the function.Is there anyway that I could bypass this ?

Comment: Awk's `$1` in single quotes can't be interpreted as the function's `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.So I guess I messed up somewhere else.I will take a look at the other code.

Comment: Assigning the function's positional parameters to named variables will increase the readability of your script: `local filename=$1` and `grep rcfc "$FPATH/*$filename/showport.out"`